# How can I trim this value stored in cloud Firestore using flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a flutter app. I don't want to convert the value to an Integer and want it to be stored as [75.33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGrLj.png). Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you want to save it in `double` in Firestore?

Comment: yes, double would work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending it to firebase, convert it using `.toStringAsFixed(2)`, if you want it as it is in the image:

```
double value = 75.333333333333;
print(value.toStringAsFixed(2)); //=> "75.33"

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionName').doc('docName').update({'Percentage': value.toStringAsFixed(2)});
```

`(2)` is the number of digits you want, if you want it 75.333 use `.toStringAsFixed(3)`.`